# How to copyright my deceased brother's book

Tags: copyright

When I apply to copyright my deceased brother's book, do I do it in my name?

Comment: In a question like this, you should include which country's jurisdiction you're asking about.

Comment: It does occur that listing yourself as *co-author* would allow for greater protections (or at least a lengthier copyright period in some jurisdictions).

Comment: IANAL, but I thought as soon as you write something, you technically own the copyright on it (unless you expressly waive the copyright or give it to someone else).  Again, IANAL, so this isn't legal advice, and may not even be correct, and could also depend on the jurisdiction.

Comment: @Valorum Dunno about elsewhere, but listing yourself as a coauthor when you in fact aren't would be strictly illegal in my country (though of course hard to prove), as it violates so-called "personality author's rights", i. e. the right to be correctly named as the author, which is even more fundamental than copyright (and valid indefinitely - yes it's illegal to pass Homer's work as your own, and equally illegal to pass your work as Homer's). 
And legality aside, doing so without the real author's consent is unethical.

Comment: @Divizna - If the book is currently uncopyrighted then making an edit would suffice to OP being a co-author

Comment: @Valorum 1. No, making an edit doesn't suffice to become a coauthor, a coauthor is someone who's made an essential contribution to the work. 2. All places I've heard of, a creative work is under copyright from the moment it's created.

Comment: Maybe this would be a better question for the law SE?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "apply to copyright" the book.  Copyright isn't something you apply for (at least in Berne Convention countries), but something that derives directly from the creative act.

Answer (score 13):

Not a lawyer, but in the USA one has a copyright as soon as a work is in written form (i.e. one cannot claim copyright on a work that is only in their head or imagination), so your brother owned the copyright. His estate now owns that copyright, if you are the inheritor of his estate, it should be a straightforward matter (with an attorney) to register the copyright formally.

I think the copyright would be in your brother's name, and then *assigned* to you; since you did not actually write the book.

I don't know the details of what you need to do, but it should be pretty straightforward.

When my mother died, her Will made me the sole inheritor of her estate, including her house. I did hire an attorney, but there was a clear legal path without any complications to put the house in my name so I could sell it.

I think your brother's copyright (which survives death) was part of his estate; it now belongs to the inheritor(s) of his estate.

Comment: The copyright must be in the brother's name because it counts the expiration date from the death of the author. That's 70 years, if the mouse house doesn't manage to extend it again for the third time. That might be happening soon.

Comment: @Mindwin Agreed.

Answer (score 4):

Such a work would have been under copyright as soon as your brother wrote it down. More specifically, a new work is protected by copyright  as soon as it is "fixed in tangible form". This includes a work written on paper, a work saved in a computer file, and a work saved as an audio or video recording. There is no need to "copyright" the work, and indeed no way of doing so.

This is true in the US, the UK, the various EU countries, and every country that adheres to the [Berne Copyright Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) or the [WTO TRIPS Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIPS_Agreement), and that is almost every country in the world.

In US law [17 USC 102](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#102) provides, in pertinent part:

> (a) Copyright protection subsists, in accordance with this title, in original works of authorship fixed in any tangible medium of expression, now known or later developed, from which they can be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid of a machine or device.

[17 USC 201(a)](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap2.html) provides that:

> (a) Initial Ownership.—Copyright in a work protected under this title vests initially in the author or authors of the work. The authors of a joint work are coowners of copyright in the work.

However, it may be desirable to ***register*** a copyright. In the US a copyright must be registered before any suit for its infringement may be brought. Registration provides a public record of the ownership of the copyright, and has other benefits.   In the US works can be registered at https://www.copyright.gov/registration/ There is a fee. However, a lawyer is not required.

One should register the copyright showing both the original author, and the claimed current owner, who in this case would be different people.

There was mention made in comments of claiming to be a co-author of the work. In the US, [17 USC 101](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#101) defines a "joint work" as:

> a work prepared by two or more authors with the intention that their contributions be merged into inseparable or interdependent parts of a unitary whole.

There is no law on how much each joint author, (co-author) must have contributed to the joint work, but such a claim by one who had made no contribution at all would be fraud, although that might be hard to prove.

A copyright is property, and at the author's death it descends like other property, by will or by the relevant law of intestate (no-will) succession, which varies by jurisdiction. It could also have been sold or given away by the author before his death.

Two or more people could be joint owners of a copyright if it was left to them jointly, or if one sold or gave a part-interest to another.

The relevant US law is [17 USC 201(d)] which provides:

> (d) Transfer of Ownership.—
>
> (1) The ownership of a copyright may be transferred in whole or in part by any means of conveyance or by operation of law, and may be bequeathed by will or pass as personal property by the applicable laws of intestate succession.
>
> (2) Any of the exclusive rights comprised in a copyright, including any subdivision of any of the rights specified by section 106, may be transferred as provided by clause (1) and owned separately. The owner of any particular exclusive right is entitled, to the extent of that right, to all of the protection and remedies accorded to the copyright owner by this title.

also relevant is [17 USC 204(a)](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap2.html#204) which provides:

> (a) A transfer of copyright ownership, other than by operation of law, is not valid unless an instrument of conveyance, or a note or memorandum of the transfer, is in writing and signed by the owner of the rights conveyed or such owner’s duly authorized agent.

[17 USC 205(a)](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap2.html#205) provides;

> (a) Conditions for Recordation.—Any transfer of copyright ownership or other document pertaining to a copyright may be recorded in the Copyright Office if the document filed for recordation bears the actual signature of the person who executed it, or if it is accompanied by a sworn or official certification that it is a true copy of the original, signed document. A sworn or official certification may be submitted to the Copyright Office electronically, pursuant to regulations established by the Register of Copyrights.

This could include a will leaving a copyright.

[The above is more or less the answer I would have given on Law.SE]

Comment: +1, A better answer with more detail than my own, readers.